# How to use the js-cookie kit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  Cookies.set("show", "on", {
    expires: 365
  });
  $("#js-tips").css("display", "none");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  let tips = Cookies.get("show");
  console.log(tips);

  if (tips === "on") {
    $("#js-tips").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $("#js-tips").css("display", "inline-block");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tips {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/3.0.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tips" id="js-tips">
  <p>hello world!</p>
  <button id="btn">i see</button>
</div>
```

I use a package called js-cookie, I hope that a welcome window will appear on the web page at the beginning. After clicking the button, the js-cookie plugin can be used to record the cookie in the user's browser, and the next time the user comes to this website, it will be recorded. This welcome window will not appear again, and I hope this record can be recorded for one year, but I don’t know which logic is wrong. The current method is a failure. I hope I can get everyone’s help, thank you.

Or someone knows how to use the original js to set the cookie method to achieve this effect, and also hope to share with me, thank you.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
  Cookies.set('tips', '1', {
    expires: 365
  })
  $('#js-tips').css('display', 'none');
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  let tips = Cookie.get('tips');

  if (tips == 1) {
    $('#js-tips').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('#js-tips').css('display', 'inline-block');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tips {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/3.0.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tips" id="js-tips">
  <p>hello world!</p>
  <button id="btn">i see</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?  Such as `ReferenceError: Cookie is not defined`?

Comment: Yes, I just rewritten it again ~
but the situation still does not improve

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/ZEoMBOQ

Comment: `let tips = Cookie.get('tips');` -> `let tips = Cookies.get('tips');`  (for a starter)

Comment: If you add `console.log(Cookies.get("show"));` (or 'tips') directly after setting it, it comes back `undefined` - so there's clearly *something* not working in the Cookies code.  https://jsfiddle.net/s1jr2hp0/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have made a correction here! But the situation is still the same ~
what is confusing is that the console.log comes out as undefined?

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/ZEoMBOQ?editors=1111

Comment: This looks like something specific to stack-snippets / jsfiddle / codepen.io - they're blocking changes to `document.cookie`.   I copied your code to a test website and it worked fine.  I also tried some other "cookie tests" in existing jsfiddles (found via Google) and they also did not work.

Comment: @freedomn-m
Thank you, it is indeed possible that it is a problem with the environment!
But I put the program on my computer and it doesn't seem to work